# How does reverse method build URL?

Tags: django

I am new to Django,learning frorm Django by Example book
This is the get_absolute_url method from Post class

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, 
        self.publish.strftime('%m'),
        self.publish.strftime('%d'),
        self.slug])
```

I am looking at source code [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/urls/base/#reverse)

```
def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None):
    if urlconf is None:
        urlconf = get_urlconf()
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
    args = args or []
    kwargs = kwargs or {}
```

Arguments part is clear to me.

```
def get_urlconf(default=None):
    """
    Return the root URLconf to use for the current thread if it has been
    changed from the default one.
    """
    return getattr(_urlconfs, "value", default)
```

But how will the urlconf be resolved?

Comment: What's not clear from the source? If urlconf is not provided, it calls the `get_urlconf()` function.

Comment: Ok,and what is the return of get_urlconf in my case?